# Sublime autocomple: Is it possible to preserve the case of typed letters in plain-text file?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

When I type: **Te** sublime provides a long autocomplete list like:

**test, tested, team, testing, testphp, .....** (These words are exiting in the current text file)

Then I choose **tested** from the list and press tab, autocomplete happens and finish the word as:

**tested**

Now What I want is to preserve the case of the 1st letter (that is **T** in this example). It should not change the case of already typed characters.

The word after completion should be:

**Tested**

Is that possible with any sublime setting or a package?

Answer (score 0):

Sublime's autocomplete is case-sensitive, because so many programming languages are as well. For example, in Python, `test` and `Test` are completely different identifiers and can't be used interchangeably. So, if you only have `test` somewhere in your buffer (or project), and you type in <kbd>T</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will autocomplete as `test`, not `Test`. However, if you have both `test` and `Test` already existing in the buffer, it will autocomplete <kbd>T</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> properly as `Test`.

[Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) does not appear to have any plugins that are related to case-insensitive autocomplete, although with the current Sublime Text 4 [API](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api_reference.html) including classes such as [`CompletionList`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api_reference.html#sublime.CompletionList) and [`CompletionItem`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api_reference.html#sublime.CompletionItem), it should be possible to write such a plugin.